# Создание адаптивной шапки сайта

Tags: html, css

Какой должен быть формат кода header'а чтобы в левой части был логотип, а в правой части навигационное меню с 5 кнопками? Но нужно, чтобы при маштабировании они центрировались по вертикали.

Comment: Вы хотите это на чистом HTML-CSS, или какая-то библиотека (типа bootstrap) будет подключена?

Comment: Да, на чистом HTML-CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```css
.logo>img { height: 30px; }
header>div { display: inline-block; }
header>div:nth-child(2) { float: right; }
.topMenu {text-align: right; }
.topMenu a { display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px; border-left: 1px solid gray;}
.topMenu a:hover { background-color: lightgray; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  header>div { display: block; text-align: center; width: 100%; }
  .topMenu {text-align: center; }
  
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="topMenu">
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: А если уже есть картинка логотипа, но она слишком большых размеров, можно ли как-то подогнать ?

Comment: Ну у меня так сделано. Лого гугла намного больше, просто я поставил `height 30px;`... чем Вам не подходит этот вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, слегка опоздал. Делается при помощи media query, почитай https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.header a {
  line-height: 75px;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: row
  }
  .header a {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/dc44181440ceb1db8b0e0334cfd27e4d/1453991975/1488/997245/twitter_logo_75x75.png">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/">twit</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/">twit</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/">twit</a>
</div>
```